# Migrating Zabbix host to new server

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I am bringing up a new Zabbix 2.2.1 server and want to migrate my hosts to it one at a time.  The kicker is that I also want to migrate their data (history & trends). The old and new servers are physically separate boxes but do have LAN connectivity so a migration process that includes exporting from one DB and importing to the other would work... just not sure about the particulars of making this work.  Any tips?  BTW, the old server is 2.0.x (always latest version) and MySQL is the backend.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I moved Zabbix (it was also a 1.8-2.0) I made the new server's MySQL server a replication slave, waited for replication to finish, and then broke replication and stopped slave on the new server. Started up Zabbix, changed DNS entries, and voila.

Comment: I want to move one host at a time as opposed to a wholesale move.

Comment: Moving all at once would be _much easier_ and less risky. I do not recommend moving "one host at a time" as this will be very time consuming and potentially much more error-prone.

Comment: It's only easier if you can touch every host at one time and you are reusing the server name... neither of which works for me.

Comment: If you can't touch every host at one time, then you need to fix that, too.

Comment: One project at a time.